# Vue v-html not render \r \n \t

Tags: html, regex, vue.js, render

I have data like this :

```
data: {
  content:"<p><span style=\"font-size:16px\">Berikut adalah beberapa pemberontakan yang pernah terjadi di daerah.</span></p>\r\n\r\n<p><span style=\"font-size:16px\"><strong>1. Pemberontakan Angkatan Perang Ratu Adil (APRA) </strong></span></p>\r\n\r\n<ul>\r\n\t<li><span style=\"font-size:16px\">di Bandung, pada 23 Januari 1950.</span></li>"
}
```

From the data I want to display it using Vue js.

This is my Vue js code:

```
<div class="row px-3" v-html="data.content"></div>
```

And if the above code is executed then the result is like this :
[image]

You can see, \r \n and \t don't seem to be rendering by Vue js

How to get \r \n and \t to be rendered by Vue js and can display as below?

[image]

Comment: Putting returns and newlines in your markup is probably not the right way to do this.  Use a stylesheet, or simply rely on Vue's "normal" way of doing things.

Comment: In my current state the data source is immutable. is there a way to render such existing data immutable?

Comment: What does immutability have to do with rendering data?

Comment: I mean that the source of the data that I will render cannot be changed, so there must be \r \n and \t in the data. You suggest that using a stylesheet means that the data source has to be changed. while in my condition, the data source cannot be changed

Comment: No, I am suggesting that you don't need \r and \n in the data to make this work.

Comment: Stylesheets don't change data; they just change the way that data is displayed.

Comment: Instead of trying to use a span to render a bullet, why not try using a `<li>`?  (Or v-li or whatever it is in Vue)  You'll automatically get the spacing you want, no need for /r/n.

Answer (score 1):

`\r`, `\n`, and `\t` are not valid HTML; they are escape sequences that are used in *other* languages (so expecting them to work in HTML would be like pasting python code into a javascript file and expecting it to run.) You need to replace them with HTML that does what you want it to do. For new lines, the `<br>` tag could be used, but traditionally people handle line breaks by wrapping their sections in paragraphs (`<p>`) or divs (`<div>`). For tabs, you'll need to google for how to handle indenting in HTML as there is a lot more to say about it than I can explain in a short answer here.

Comment: It's not valid, but should work no ? in jsfiddle simple copy/paste display a good visual

Comment: Here's some examples: https://jsfiddle.net/bgm8eqta/

Comment: See with innerHTML : https://jsfiddle.net/Minart/bpqrhfoc/

Comment: I think you must be missing something in your question, because it works fine for me: https://jsfiddle.net/L54r6qdm/ I used your exact text, and the \r\n is not showing up in the output. Can you post more of your code?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the complete code, but after first read :

Try

```
v-html="content"
```

and

```
data(){
   return {
      content: "<p><span style=\"font-size:16px\">Berikut adalah beberapa pemberontakan yang pernah terjadi di daerah.</span></p>\r\n\r\n<p><span style=\"font-size:16px\"><strong>1. Pemberontakan Angkatan Perang Ratu Adil (APRA) </strong></span></p>\r\n\r\n<ul>\r\n\t<li><span style=\"font-size:16px\">di Bandung, pada 23 Januari 1950.</span></li>"
   }
}
```

Comment: I've tried it but it still doesn't work